# Links to container in networking with docker-compose

Tags: docker, url, networking, docker-compose

My aim is to access a container via URL from another container using docker-compose.

So, suppose i have the following `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: web
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

and a Dockerfile `Dockerfile` in the folder `web`

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN ping postgres://db:5432
```

Running `docker-compose build` returns

```
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:3.7
 ---> 6d1ef012b567
Step 2/2 : RUN ping postgres://db:5432
 ---> Running in afbfcd27b340
ping: bad address 'postgres://db:5432'
Service 'web' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c ping postgres://db:5432' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The docs for networking in docker compose (
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links) states:

> Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432 and start using the Postgres database.

What is the correct URL the connect to the container obtained from service db?

Comment: You can't connect to other containers from within a Dockerfile.  (Also `ping` sends packets using a very low-level protocol, ICMP, and doesn't understand URLs at all.)

Answer (score 1):

During the `web` image build, your `db` container does not exist, so using RUN is incorrect here.

One option would to include the CMD command in the Dockerfile which will instruct the `web` container to run the `ping` command every time the container is started up.

Also, I've adjusted the argument being passed to the `ping` command.

So, the `web` Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

CMD ["ping", "db:5432"]
```

Now, after `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, you will see that the `web` container pings the `db` container on part 5432 and receives a response.

`docker-compose` starts a bridge network and adds all of the containers to this network so they can communicate with each other. Each container's hostname is the same as their service name in the docker-compose file. The hostnames are resoved by an internal DNS service.